# Running code supplied by course but keep getting: Syntax error: Unexpected identifier "bike_id" at [3:5]

Tags: error-handling, syntax

I am using austin_bike_data...using the table austin_bikeshare_trips I created a temptable then joined the temp table to austin_bikeshare_trips. I keep getting a syntax error for bike_id. I tried to used the alias of the austin_bikeshare_trips table but did not solve the problem

```
WITH
  longest_used_bike AS (
    bike_id,
  SELECT
    bike_id,
    SUM(duration_minutes) AS trip_duration
  FROM
    temporary-415218.austin_bike_data.austin_bikeshare_trips
  GROUP BY
    bike_id
  ORDER BY
    trip_duration DESC
  LIMIT 1
  )
## find station where the longest-used bike leaves most often
SELECT
  trips.start_station_id,
  COUNT(*) AS trip_ct
FROM
  longest_used_bike AS longest
INNER JOIN
  temporary-415218.austin_bike_data.austin_bikeshare_trips AS trips
ON longest.bike_id = trips.bike_id
GROUP BY
  trips.start_station_id
ORDER BY
  trip_ct DESC
  LIMIT 1
```